# Nginx/1.0.15 Centos 6 Displaying 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, nginx

I just set up nginx/1.0.15 on my centos 6 VPS without using a domain and just using the VPS IP to set up.  I used the following guide to set it up:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-6

I also installed phpMyAdmin as well.

I set everything up and all went smooth but now I've added a domain name to it and edited /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf to allow for the new domain:

```
#
server {
listen       80;
server_name  customads.net;
```

I can view some files such as:

http://customads.net/test.html

Which is just a h1 with some random text to see if it would display,

Also I created a test php page:

http://customads.net/testphp.php

Which is just:

```
<?php
echo "Testing PHP Echo";
?>
```

Also when I try to do any SQL query in phpMyAdmin I always receive this error message:

```
import.php: Missing parameter: import_type
import.php: Missing parameter: format
```

However it works when I query straight from ssh.

Would anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> mkdir /var/lib/php/session
>   chmod 777 /var/lib/php/session

Verify that your `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` contains

> php_value[session.save_handler] = files
>    php_value[session.save_path] = /var/lib/php/session